# Accessing container properties from child list

Tags: c#, oop, properties, domain-driven-design, parent-child

I have a container class called PaymentPlan, which holds basic Payment summary info.  It also holds a list of ExpectedPayments.  Hopefully a fairly basic OOP type question, my brain appears to have gone to sleep - I have a property in the ExpectedPayment class which needs to interrogate a property on the PaymentPlan class to determine the result.

I'm currently storing a reference to the PaymentPlan as a property on the ExpectedPayment class, however, it has a public getter, and following DDD, I feel this is a bit of a code smell.  Is there a better way to achieve what I want?

I've removed all but the necessary bits as an example:

```
public class PaymentPlan
{
    private readonly List<ExpectedPayment> _payments;

    public PaymentPlan(List<ExpectedPayment> payments)
    {
        ... Other Stuff

        //TODO: Fix this smell
        _payments = payments;
        _payments.ForEach(p => p.Plan = this);
    }

    ... Other Properties
}
```

And the ExpectedPayment class:

```
public class ExpectedPayment
{
    public ExpectedPayment(... Args removed for example)
    {
    }

    //TODO: Attempting to avoid this public setter as I have no control..
    public PaymentPlan Plan { get; set; }

    public PaymentState PaymentState
    {
        get
        {
            if (Plan.SomePropertyOnPlan == "SomeValue")
            {
                return PaymentState.SomeState;
            }
            else 
            {
                ... Other logic to determine the payment state of this expected payment.
            }
        }
    }

    ... Other Properties

}
```

Any help appreciated! - I would like to know some techniques if possible as know there are multiple ways to achieve what I'm after.

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: In your business logic, Can ExpectedPayment not have any PaymentPlan ?

Comment: The ExpectedPayments are linked to 1 plan. There is a 1 - many between PaymentPlan and ExpectedPayment, the ExpectedPayments can't be associated with any other plan. (possibly another smell in my code?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As if `ExpectedPayment` shouldn't exist if it hasn't any `PaymentPlan`, you must force your `ExpectedPayment()` constructor to provide `PaymentPlan` to caller and add a "friendly" method for adding new `ExpectedPlan` on `PaymentPlan` .

```
public class ExpectedPayment
{
    public ExpectedPayment(PaymentPlan plan, ..... other args)
    {
        Plan = plan ; 
        plan.AddExpectedPlan(this) ; 
        ......
    }

    ......
```

....

```
public class PaymentPlan 
{
    .........

    internal void AddExpectedPlan(ExpectedPlan expectedPlan) 
    { 
        ...........
        _payments.Add(expectedPlan) ; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Ah yes, I see, that makes a little more sense! Thanks very much! I'll give that a whirl.